# Вопрос у приложения несколько скинов, как лучше сделать переключение по ним

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вопрос у приложения несколько скинов, как лучше сделать переключение по ним. Загружать активити с нужным xml не подходит хотелось бы без перезапуска приложения. Переключаться между активити думаю не очень правильно. просто поменять картинки у view тоже не подходит так как каждый скин с изменениями в layout и некоторые view прийдеться скрывать/показывать.
Возможно ли без перезапуска приложения пересоздать активити??
Или может какие то другие решения есть...

Comment: у активити есть метод recreate(), который пересоздает ее

Comment: Спасибо, в этой ситуации это лучший вариант да??

Comment: не знаю. я с вашей реализацей не знаком, чтобы определять ее варианты. Вы спросили, как пересоздать активити без перезапуска приложения - я написал про метод, который это делает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recreate() не подошел так как переопределенные методы переставали работать.
чтобы перезагрузить активити отлично работает вот что:

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
```